# # npm audit report nedb * Severity: critical underscore 1.3.2 - 1.12.0 binary-search-tree *

Tags: node.js, npm

## npm audit report

nedb  *
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-339j-hqgx-qrrx
Depends on vulnerable versions of binary-search-tree
Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
No fix available
node_modules/nedb

underscore  1.3.2 - 1.12.0
Severity: critical
node_modules/binary-search-tree/node_modules/underscore
node_modules/nedb/node_modules/underscore
binary-search-tree  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
node_modules/binary-search-tree

3 critical severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

npm audit fix --force

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.